# How long did it takes to have google place API Key

Tags: key, checkin

I have filled the form for Google Place API but no answer from Google...
Any idea for the time required to have this Key ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your request corresponds to [criteria](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Requirements)?